# Estimating population mean when using biased sampling?

Tags: sampling, mean, bias

Say you had a sample of 50 items that was constructed by taking selecting values that were in the top 75% (not in the first quartile), and you had to take 61 items to find those 50 (11 were in the bottom quartile).

How could one go about constructing an estimate of the population mean for the data from this knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the parametric distribution of the population?  (ex: is it normal, poisson...?)

You likely can make an educated guess about the population distribution if you have data from the upper 75% of the distribution. You then have to fit the distribution using only the upper 75%, and then you can get an estimate of the population mean.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, the distribution is normal. Thanks!

Comment: Fitting the distribution using only the upper 75% is not a direct process, however. Most algorithms will assume you have handed them a full set if samples from the distribution. Note that in normal, however, population mean= population median, which might help also.

Comment: If that answers your question, don't forget to accept!